# What is the Linux or UNIX command for creating new processes?

Tags: filesystems, terminal, rhel

What is the Linux or UNIX command for
creating new processes?

Answer (score 2):

A new process gets created by the OS each time you run a command in a shell or double-click an application icon in a window environment. There is no special command as such (wouldn‘t make a lot of sense anyway as a process needs program code to execute).

If you are wondering how the OS does it, have a look at `fork()` and `execve()`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099707) on StackOverflow gives a nice example of how this works.